# Does anybody want to help with the Grammar Girl interview?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, blog

As I said in [this meta post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1963/were-going-to-be-on-the-grammar-girl-podcast-what-do-we-want-her-to-say-about-u), we're going to be on the [Grammar Girl](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/) podcast. I think a great way to attract her listeners to our site would be to do an interview with her before hand and write it up on our blog. I know a few people have expressed interest in [writing for the blog](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1426/call-for-blog-participation), so I was hoping that some of you would be interested in helping out with the interview and write up. Please respond here if you are! Also feel free to email me at lauren@stackexchange.com

[**Edit**] I just heard from Mignon (Grammar Girl) again and she said it's easiest for her to answer interview questions over email. So we really just need help putting together a list of questions, and then a volunteer to correspond with her and write up the blog post.

[**Edit**] Even if you don't want to do the interview or write the post, we could still use suggestions for questions to ask her. So please [post your ideas as answers here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2002/what-are-we-going-to-ask-grammar-girl)!

Comment: Are we looking to interview her, or is she interviewing us?

Comment: We'll be interviewing her. Sorry if I wasn't clear!

Comment: So would it be best to just put prospective interview questions here as "answers", and give her the top voted ones? Kind of like how slashdot does interviews.

Comment: You're welcome to suggest questions here if you'd like - that would be a good way to get more people involved. But I'm still looking for someone to help organize the interview and write up the blog post!

Answer (score 1):

I guess I will volunteer to organize the interview and write the blog post, however, I have no idea what questions to ask, and I even visited her site and read a few posts. What kind of subject matter are we thinking to cover?

Comment: Thanks for volunteering! We can really cover whatever you think would be interesting to our community and her listeners (the goal is to give her something to refer her listeners to when she mentions us in the podcast). Maybe questions about her background, how she started doing this, where she gets topic ideas? Let's get creative - and we can take suggestions from other EL&U users - I'll edit this post to ask for ideas.